# Is wildcard possible in Flutter Firestore query?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

My goal is to stream all messages in the database from the path 'chat/$chattype/room/{roomID}/message' where I need to query all messages that has a document with a string that has 'user1' in it, without explicitly specifying the rooms id. Can't seem to get it working with an wildcard, but..
is it possible to query from say: 'chat/$chattype/room/' instead?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('chat/$chattype/room/{roomID}/message')
          .where("reciever", isEqualTo: "user1")
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to query multiple collections is with a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which queries all collections with a given name.

So:

```
_firestore
      .collectionGroup('message')
      .where("reciever", isEqualTo: "user1")
      .snapshots(),
```

Also see the Flutter reference documentation for [`collectionGroup()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore/collectionGroup.html).

Comment: I can see how that will work, thanks. However, wouldn't that be a great burden on the database? I mean, if I for instance have a million messages it has to search through, rather than specifying $chattype, which would cut it down to maybe only a 1000 searches?

Comment: Firestore developers are way ahead of you.  Most of Firestore performance comes from indexing; you will need to either create a collectionGroup index, OR when you first run the query Firestore will give an error message with a link to automatically create the index for you.  No performance lost at all.

Comment: Due to how Firestore indexes data, it actually is no additional burden. To allow a collection group query, you must define an index on that collection group. And that index is where Firestore starts the query. Writing data is the more common throughput limit for Firestore, which is why I'd recommend finding a unique name for the collections in the group you want to query (`chat/$chattype/room/{roomID}/message`). So if you have `message` collections elsewhere in Firestore too, it might be worth naming these something like `chatroommessages`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) I will read more on collectionGrouping.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore queries do not support any wildcards.  You must be able to build a full path to a collection in order to query it.

You might also want to look into [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) which let you query all documents in any subcollection with the same name.  You might be able to use a collection group query on "message" to query all messages for **all** chat types for **all** rooms, applying a filter from there if needed.