# Fetch data from subcollection document in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, collections

This is my data structure. Here are the list of users documents.[image]

and here is the subcollection in every document.[image]

The subcollection is containing strongly typed document which is form.

What I want is to fetch ***form*** document (not for the current user) from subcollection workerField from every ***users*** document.
what is the implementation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load documents from all `workerField` collections you can use a so-called [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

So something like:

```
var docs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collectionGroup('workerField')
      .snapshots();
```

See my answer here for another example: [Is wildcard possible in Flutter Firestore query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329139/is-wildcard-possible-in-flutter-firestore-query/63329166#63329166) and more from these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+is%3Aanswer+collection+group+query).

Comment: okay. but suppose I have two different collections and both have uid as a document field. I query collection 1 to retrieve all documents in collection. How am I gonna query second collection with uid from collection 1. Ps I am using one  future builder to display data.

Comment: That seems like a different problem, so I recommend opening a new question for it. If it's the same problem, please edit your question to show in code what you tried - as I'm having a hard time parsing it from your description.